# Q: DevExpress TreeListLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress, desktop

[image]

[image]

i want to add the button like plus beside the dropdown button like the picture

I don't have a problem writing the problematic code. I want to add a button in the outline design of the TreeListLookUpEdi. When I click on this button, which resembles the plus icon in the image, I add code.
Like opening a new window and adding new items to TreeListLookUpEdit

Comment: Please post what you have attempted and specific questions regarding your code or any errors.

Comment: I don't have a problem writing the problematic code. I want to add a button in the outline design of the TreeListLookUpEdi. When I click on this button, which resembles the plus icon in the image, I add code.
Like opening a new window and adding new items to TreeListLookUpEdit

Comment: Please specify your exact question. Your post doesn't even contain a question mark. You'll need to clarify what exactly it is you are having trouble with before anyone will be able to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Runtime you can doing the following:

```
//add Plus Button 
treeListLookUpEdit1.Properties.Buttons.Add(new EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Plus));
//add ButtonPressed Event  
treeListLookUpEdit1.Properties.ButtonPressed += new ButtonPressedEventHandler(this.treeListLookUpEdit1_Properties_ButtonPressed);


private void treeListLookUpEdit1_Properties_ButtonPressed(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button.Kind == ButtonPredefines.Plus)
   { 
     //here your code 
     MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: I tried this code and it works but when I press the down button it turns on the code for the plus button

Comment: your welcome! 
I edited the code, you should specify the button type in the button press event before writing your code.